# How to ensure the setup program will run with administrator rights?

Tags: inno-setup

If I create setup package using Inno Setup, will the setup program have administrator privileges allowing it to register DLLs etc. ?

Also, if the setup package executes a program as part of its operations, will that program be run with the administrator rights ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is controlled via the [`PrivilegesRequired`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_privilegesrequired.htm) directive.

> When set to `admin` (the default) or
>   `poweruser`, Setup will always run with
>   administrative privileges. If Setup
>   was started by an unprivileged user,
>   Windows will ask for the password to
>   an account that has administrative
>   privileges, and Setup will then run
>   under that account.

If the setup executes a program from the [`[Run]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_runsection.htm) section, then you can control the privileges of the spawned process with the `runascurrentuser` and `runasoriginaluser` flags.